# Representing structs in Xamarin binding

Tags: ios, binding, struct, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am trying my first binding project, and I have got most of my methods working. I can't work out how to bind the following structs though:

```
typedef struct StarPrinterStatus_
{
  // printer status 1
  SM_BOOLEAN coverOpen;
  SM_BOOLEAN offline;
  SM_BOOLEAN compulsionSwitch;

  // printer status 2
  SM_BOOLEAN overTemp;
  SM_BOOLEAN unrecoverableError;
  SM_BOOLEAN cutterError;
  SM_BOOLEAN mechError;

  // printer status 3
  SM_BOOLEAN pageModeCmdError;
  SM_BOOLEAN paperSizeError;
  SM_BOOLEAN presenterPaperJamError;
  SM_BOOLEAN headUpError;

  // printer status 4
  SM_BOOLEAN blackMarkDetectStatus;
  SM_BOOLEAN paperEmpty;
  SM_BOOLEAN paperNearEmptyInner;
  SM_BOOLEAN paperNearEmptyOuter;

  // printer status 5
  SM_BOOLEAN stackerFull;

  // printer status 6
  SM_BOOLEAN etbAvailable;
  UCHAR etbCounter;

  // printer status 7
  UCHAR presenterState;

  // raw
  UINT32 rawLength;
  UCHAR raw[63];
} StarPrinterStatus, StarPrinterStatus_0;

typedef struct StarPrinterStatus_1_
{
  // printer status 1
  SM_BOOLEAN coverOpen;
  SM_BOOLEAN offline;
  SM_BOOLEAN compulsionSwitch;

  // printer status 2
  SM_BOOLEAN overTemp;
  SM_BOOLEAN unrecoverableError;
  SM_BOOLEAN cutterError;
  SM_BOOLEAN mechError;

  // printer status 3
  SM_BOOLEAN receiveBufferOverflow;
  SM_BOOLEAN pageModeCmdError;
  SM_BOOLEAN blackMarkError;
  SM_BOOLEAN presenterPaperJamError;
  SM_BOOLEAN headUpError;

  // printer status 4
  SM_BOOLEAN receiptBlackMarkDetection;
  SM_BOOLEAN receiptPaperEmpty;
  SM_BOOLEAN receiptPaperNearEmptyInner;
  SM_BOOLEAN receiptPaperNearEmptyOuter;

  // printer status 5
  SM_BOOLEAN presenterPaperPresent;
  SM_BOOLEAN peelerPaperPresent;
  SM_BOOLEAN stackerFull;
  SM_BOOLEAN slipTOF;
  SM_BOOLEAN slipCOF;
  SM_BOOLEAN slipBOF;
  SM_BOOLEAN validationPaperPresent;
  SM_BOOLEAN slipPaperPresent;

  // printer status 6
  SM_BOOLEAN etbAvailable;
  UCHAR etbCounter;

  // printer status 7
  UCHAR presenterState;

  // raw
  UINT32 rawLength;
  UCHAR raw[63];
} StarPrinterStatus_1;

typedef struct StarPrinterStatus_2_
{
  // printer status 1
  SM_BOOLEAN coverOpen;
  SM_BOOLEAN offline;
  SM_BOOLEAN compulsionSwitch;

  // printer status 2
  SM_BOOLEAN overTemp;
  SM_BOOLEAN unrecoverableError;
  SM_BOOLEAN cutterError;
  SM_BOOLEAN mechError;
  SM_BOOLEAN headThermistorError;

  // printer status 3
  SM_BOOLEAN receiveBufferOverflow;
  SM_BOOLEAN pageModeCmdError;
  SM_BOOLEAN blackMarkError;
  SM_BOOLEAN presenterPaperJamError;
  SM_BOOLEAN headUpError;
  SM_BOOLEAN voltageError;

  // printer status 4
  SM_BOOLEAN receiptBlackMarkDetection;
  SM_BOOLEAN receiptPaperEmpty;
  SM_BOOLEAN receiptPaperNearEmptyInner;
  SM_BOOLEAN receiptPaperNearEmptyOuter;

  // printer status 5
  SM_BOOLEAN presenterPaperPresent;
  SM_BOOLEAN peelerPaperPresent;
  SM_BOOLEAN stackerFull;
  SM_BOOLEAN slipTOF;
  SM_BOOLEAN slipCOF;
  SM_BOOLEAN slipBOF;
  SM_BOOLEAN validationPaperPresent;
  SM_BOOLEAN slipPaperPresent;

  // printer status 6
  SM_BOOLEAN etbAvailable;
  UCHAR etbCounter;

  // printer status 7
  UCHAR presenterState;

  // raw
  UINT32 rawLength;
  UCHAR raw[63];
} StarPrinterStatus_2;
```

They are called on the following method:

```
- (void)getParsedStatus:(void *)starPrinterStatus :(u_int32_t)level;
```

Which I am trying to bind to:

```
    [Export ("getParsedStatus::")]
    void GetParsedStatus (??? starPrinterStatus, int level);
```

I'm really at a loss though as to how I represent this in my binding. These are all part of the Star Micronics iOS SDK.

Comment: have you figured this out?